# Dupont wire connection sensitivity

Tags: connector, wiring, wire

I'm at my wit's end trying to figure out methods to separate Dupont wires.

I ordered an 8 pin SOIC clip from eBay.  Due to low funds I had to opt for the cheapest alternative. It arrived along with a 40 bundle of Dupont wires.

Initially, after attempting to connect the Dupont wires to the clip, I noticed that the Dupont connector is too large for the clip (4 connectors to a side) to fit all 4 sides of the clip. After stripping the clip's plastic fitting out of it to a barebones wire with the metallic adapter it fits.

[image: photo of SOIC cip and wire connectors]

<sub>[Link to original large image on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTVaw.jpg)</sub>

Will the Dupont wire connector as a barebones metallic adapter short out my chip if I use it to connect it to a Raspberry Pi?

I'm trying to get it to a state where I can reprogram the chip with my Raspberry Pi without shorting it.

Would using paper in between be sufficient to stop it from frying? Nothing else will fit to separate it unless there is an alternative I could do with household items. There really isn't any alternatives for me as I can't afford a "Pomona" clip due to their expensive pricing.

Comment: As an alternative to of paper you might use tape, some leftover insulation of thicker wires or heat shrink tube (if available). But please post some photos so we will be able to help you better.

Comment: Yeah pics or it didn't happen.  Electrical tape is relatively cheap and 300V/layer.

Comment: Are you faking this one? https://www.pomonaelectronics.com/products/test-clips/soic-clip-8-pin.

Comment: But the upper pins "between-distance" is a standard 0.1", how come there is any problem? https://www.pomonaelectronics.com/file/17722/download?token=nukrOMxz.

Comment: Usually I DIY my own DuPont connecting cables: Dupont-Male and Female PCB Connector Kits, 1450pcs / set, 2.54mm, Electronic Terminal Connector
https://es.aliexpress.com/item/1005002120247975.html?spm=a2g0o.search0302.0.0.75022ce7Mhvagz&algo_pvid=c06f9bbf-57b0-48ff-b53a-7eb4ea2b0f79&algo_expid=c06f9bbf-57b0-48ff-b53a-7eb4ea2b0f79-13&btsid=0b0a556316156983259783841e0a63&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_.

Comment: And I usually use clips cheaper than eBay: SOP8 clip ¥9 - TaoBao
https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a312a.7700824.w4002-14787471864.49.4dd418c2wtYoHh&id=575670106541

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/xrThniT image as requested

Comment: @m3troidman - Hi, Thanks, I have added that image "inline" in the question. I can see you would be unable to do that, as the jpg file was about 3.5 MB straight from the camera (?), and a max size of 2 MB is allowed here. It is common that camera photos have to be resized before they can be uploaded, as original images are just too big and high-resolution to be added here directly. I proportionally resized your photo down to 700 pixels wide and its size went from 3.5 MB to 72 kB (!) so it could then be uploaded here. Hope that helps for future questions.

Comment: @m3troidman, I see that you have one pin DuPont female connector. I usually use a twizzer to lift up the locking flap and pull out the bare metal female pin (takes me less than two seconds) and insert the one pin into a 4-pin empty DuPont adapter. This way you can, in less than one minute,  convert four 1-pin DuPont female connector into one 4-pin female connector.

Comment: You can also use this: Heat Shrinkable Polyolefin Tube Set, Shrink Wire Cable, Insulation, US3.60 / (164 pcs) box
https://es.aliexpress.com/item/4000200124003.html?spm=a2g0o.search0302.0.0.77934cd8IdG5qm&algo_pvid=1ca96777-2b19-419c-9514-959407efcef7&algo_expid=1ca96777-2b19-419c-9514-959407efcef7-7&btsid=0bb0624416157707839724203ea628&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is an insulator will work.  Paper is about as inexpensive as you can get.

I will attempt to describe in words what I might do.

Cut a strip of paper that is somewhat taller than the bare part of the pins.  Zig-zag the paper between the pins.  Take the free ends of the paper strip and wrap around the full row of pins.  Tape in place.

Answer (score 1):

Bend the pins alternately up and down. If you want all the push-ons parallel then bend them again the opposite direction so they are alternately kinked.

```
              _______
1st pin    |_/
           |
 
2nd pin    |_
           | \_______
```